# wxPython & Pyserial - Continuous communication

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, scheduling, pyserial

I am a newbie to python and I am learning new things day by day. I have a question regarding integrating wxpython and pyserial.  I am writing a GUI application to control a microprocessor through pyserial.

I have a wxpython script written - displays good - with buttons and text fields. 
I tested communication with my microprocessor using small commands from pyserial - everything is in good place.

**Problem:**

1. I will be having a button (say Button A) on my GUI, which after clicked - checks if the serial communication is made (by sending and receiving data ofcourse). Once the communication is good, I have to make sure the communication stays good as long as I am using my GUI. So I decided to write an external function which continuously sends and reads data (probably a **for** loop). Based on the functions return value I will know if my serial communication is active or not (this might be a bad idea - but thats the best I got)
2. Now the problem is I have a lot of other features on my GUI, buttons, text fields etc.. So for example when another button (say button B) is pressed I want to send a specific command to the microprocessor. This requires I interrupt the serial communication which was going on in my Step 1, send data from button B click, then re-start the Step 1 communication again (to keep checking my serial communication is active). I dont know how I can interrupt the communication. The Step 1 serial communication (for loop) is bound to the Button A click. Once the Button A is clicked, it goes to a for loop and serial communication is checked continuously.
3. I have so many buttons and text fields like this - which are going to read and write data to the Microprocessor. Whenever I want to do an event, I have to stop the serial communication in step 1 and restart it again.
4. On top of all this, I can only check the serial communication (mentioned in Step 1) every 100ms. I cannot just write a for loop. I have to do some modifications - like time.delay(100ms) or something.

I dont know how to frame it, but may be I just require a good algorithm idea or implement this somehow with help of **import sched or import thread**

I am trying majorly to avoid **import thread** - because my microprocessor has very minimal RAM. Also using threading with wxPython is pain in the neck (what I read online)

One of my colleagues suggested using "timer service" from my Operating system. I dont think python have a feature like that. I have no clue what he is talking about, at the least. His argument is that, if I can use this, I can run the continuous serial communication check every 100ms very easily.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not looking for any complicated solutions, I appreciate if you attach a piece of code, use very basic programming. I have the wxPython GUI in a single class.

Comment: you can use threads with wx, just use wx.CallAfter when not in the main thread and everything will be fine: https://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter

Comment: threading is absolutely the right answer here ... wx.Timer just fires an event ... you would have to catch that event and then call your function ... while your function is running it will still block

Comment: Still looking for answers

Comment: I have almost the same requirement as yourself: *Did you ever solve your problem?*